# Chromium vs. YouTube questions closed to a dead end

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions

Fortunately it still is easy to find the solution for non-playing YouTube content on Chromium from the relevant questions here but closing of these questions led to an unfortunate constellation:

1. [Chromium browser not loading youtube video](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309610/chromium-browser-not-loading-youtube-video)
   is closed as a dupe from question 2. where the answer links back to 1.
2. [Can't watch youtube videos with chromium on ubuntu 13.04 64-bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300104/cant-watch-youtube-videos-with-chromium-on-ubuntu-13-04-64-bit)
   links to 1. in the most upvoted answer but the question is closed too, it is a dupe of another question:
3. [Youtube says "This video is currently unavailable"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234871/chromium-on-ubuntu-12-04-youtube-says-this-video-is-currently-unavailable)
   but this was closed as NARQ.

So we now have a maze of 3 closed questions for this issue. Question 1. has the best answer. Question 3. has the best title for googling but an answer that does not always work.

Let me therefore suggest to

- reopen [question 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234871/chromium-on-ubuntu-12-04-youtube-says-this-video-is-currently-unavailable) as a new "master" question.
- merge [question 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309610/chromium-browser-not-loading-youtube-video) to question 3 to move the good answer to there.
- leave question 2 closed as dupe of 3.

Comment: Whatever you say boss.  You did the reading, and I trust your judgement on this type of thing.

Comment: where's the hammer! BRING THE HAMMER! Lets all pray for the hammer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

- [Question 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234871/youtube-says-this-video-is-currently-unavailable) has been reopened.
- [Question 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309610/chromium-browser-not-loading-youtube-video) is now merged into question 3.
- [Question 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300104/cant-watch-youtube-videos-with-chromium-on-ubuntu-13-04-64-bit) is left untouched.

Comment: Mmm... question #2 most uv answer is a link to an answer on #3.... WELP